# How to aggregate a json file?

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, talend

I want to aggregate a Json file.
I use Talend to do this so I have to make this transformation in java.
It's a order file.

```
{
"order" : [{
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Pains au lait aux pépites de chocolat, 350 g",
            "unit_price" : 2.39,
            "ean" : "3256540011465",
            "price" : 4.78,
            "quantity" : 2,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref" : "23806"
        }
    }, {
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Eau de montagne, 6 x 1.5 L",
            "unit_price" : 1.99,
            "ean" : "3596710383931",
            "price" : 1.99,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref" : "117797"
        }
    }, {
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Eau de montagne, 6 x 1.5 L",
            "unit_price" : 1.99,
            "ean" : "3596710383931",
            "price" : 1.99,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref" : "117797"
        }
    }, {
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Pains au lait aux pépites de chocolat, 350 g",
            "unit_price" : 2.39,
            "ean" : "3256540011465",
            "price" : 4.78,
            "quantity" : 2,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref" : "23806"
        }
    }
]
}
```

My file contains the items in the order, but in duplicate.

If the tag "name", "ean", "ref", "unit_price" are the same, I want to add the quantities in the same "order_line" and remove "order_line" in duplicate.

And I want this:

```
{
"order" : [{
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Pains au lait aux pépites de chocolat, 350 g",
            "unit_price" : 2.39,
            "ean" : "3256540011465",
            "price" : 4.78,
            "quantity" : 4,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref" : "23806"
        }
    }, {
        "order_line" : {
            "name" : "Eau de montagne, 6 x 1.5 L",
            "unit_price" : 1.99,
            "ean" : "3596710383931",
            "price" : 1.99,
            "quantity" : 2,
            "date" : "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0009",
            "ref_fo" : "117797"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I know how to do in XML with XSL.
But I don't know how to do this in Camel Java... Do you any idea?

Comment: Have a look at jsonPath.

Comment: You can achieve this with Talend like so: Read the json, use tAggregate on the fields you want to add, print out JSON afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you want.

1. Create an orderLine class.
2. Translate the json into java objects (jackson or gson are two tools for that, there are many others as well)
3. Sort the orderLines.
4. Combine duplicates.
5. Generate json from the new (combined) list

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using talend ESB (mediation perspective), so if you know how to do this with XSL, the simplest way to do this is perhaps to use [XSL](https://camel.apache.org/xslt.html) camel component inside a cMessagingEndpoint, and make the transformation with XSLT.
In cMessaging endpoint, you can just configure the URI field with the filepath.

"xslt:file://C:/temp/xslt.xslt"

Then link it after your input component.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes it's Talend ESB but it's Json file.
How to do this with Json ?

Comment: There is a camel component fort JOLT, which seems to be an equivalent for XSLT : https://camel.apache.org/jolt.html . I never used JOLT but it could be useful in your case